# *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804832a ***

Tags: c

I'm getting this error when I run my program. It compliles fine, it just won't run. It doesnt give me a line number, but by process of elimination it seems to be breaking on a `char` declaration.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804832a
```

and then it goes into a memory dump and ends with `Aborted (core dumped)`.

I can't post the code because its my homework, but I've been stuck for three hours and not getting anywhere. Basically just trying to read a file with `fgets()`. It looks similar to this:

```
int main( void ) {
    file *filename char line[100];  // breaks here
    fgets(line, 100, filename);
}
```

Any idea why something like this would be happening? I'm including stdio, stdlib and string?

---

Here is the entire error:

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6[0xb760a764]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x96)[0xb760c966]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_free_backup_area+0x34)[0xb7608c94]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__uflow+0x61)[0xb7609421]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_getline_info+0xa6)[0xb75fbdd6]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(_IO_getline+0x41)[0xb75fbd21]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(fgets+0xaa)[0xb75fac2a]
./a.out[0x80484ca]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5)[0xb75b2455]
./a.out[0x80483b1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 24469538   /class-service/path/to/me/a.out
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 00:14 24469538   /class-service/path/to/me/a.out
08580000-085a1000 rw-p 08580000 00:00 0          [heap]
b758e000-b759a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 897603     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b759a000-b759b000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 897603     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b759b000-b759c000 rw-p b759b000 00:00 0 
b759c000-b76f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 906061     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b76f1000-b76f2000 r--p 00155000 08:02 906061     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b76f2000-b76f4000 rw-p 00156000 08:02 906061     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so
b76f4000-b76f7000 rw-p b76f4000 00:00 0 
b7710000-b7712000 rw-p b7710000 00:00 0 
b7712000-b7713000 r-xp b7712000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7713000-b772d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 898005     /lib/ld-2.7.so
b772d000-b772f000 rw-p 0001a000 08:02 898005     /lib/ld-2.7.so
bff3f000-bff54000 rw-p bffea000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please confirm, is this line correct: `file *filename char line[100]; `. There is no semi-colon separating the declarations for `filename` and `line`. Is your real code different?

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your FILE* isn't opening a file (`FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r")`), then it's most likely crashing because `fgets(line, 100, file)` isn't able to actually read from that file (it's not an open stream).
Strictly, it's crashing because free was called on an invalid pointer (*not* a NULL pointer - the standard allows `free()` to be called on a NULL pointer), but to one whose value-pointed-to is no longer valid. This is, however, caused by your `fgets()` call.
Note that a `char filename[]` *isn't* the same as a `FILE*` that has had `fopen()` called.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pretty sure this is what I need. How do I read the filename(s) from stdin? I have a char array with fgets() setup but I'm only getting the first character returned.

Comment: if you're reading from stdin, the FILE* is already opened - and the variable is called 'stdin'!
fgets(line, 100, stdin); // note that this will read the '\n' into your array!
FILE *file = fopen(line, "r");

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it. I'll post if I have any more questions and will award answer :)

Comment: No worries. Note that i just slightly revised my comment, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is given by a call (either direct or indirect) to a `free` on a pointer which is invalid (because either it wasn't `malloc`'d or because there is a nasty heap corruption somewhere).

Comment: hrm, there isn't free() or malloc anywhere in the program..

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted it looks as if the variables are not being declared properly, plus some statements are missing.

Try running this example http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c19.htm.

Comment: ahh, so I cant just fgets() a file, I need to use fopen anf funnel that into a variable?

Comment: The fgets() library function operates on a file pointer returned by fopen(). The man pages provide information on all the standard ANSI library functions. See fgets() http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/ and fopen http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/ for instance as they detail each of their respective arguments and more.